# Why are some of my content type columns grayed off?

Tags: content-type, column

Here's what my content looks like, currently. Some of the columns are grayed off for some reason, and I can't change their visible/hidden/required status. It only happens with Integer columns. If I type in a manually crafted URL like /_layouts/ManageContentTypeField.aspx?...&Field=FieldName&Fid={GUID}, I can access those fields.

What would be the solution in this case, other than making those fields Number fields?

[image: Column list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually columns are greyed off when SharePoint doesn't want you to mess with them, because it uses them internally or for interacting with other applications.

For example, the recurring field is needed in calendar lists for synchronization with Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

To build on what Christophe said, it is possible to set a column so that it can not be modified/reconfigured or perhaps even removed.  If you use a tool like SP Administrator you should be able to see those properties.